# Animate() doesn't work with scrollTop properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a script that scrolls the page automatically to the specific element when I scroll my mouse, but for some reason my animation gets repeated and the scroll goes back and forth.

Edit:
I would like to point out that this doesn't happen if the page scrolls to the last element on the page, but if it scrolls to the second element it will bounce instantly back to the top.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
comp = 0;
current_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
console.log("CURRENT SCROLL POSITION = " +current_scroll_position);

second = $("#second").offset().top;




$(window).scroll(function(scroll_action){

    $('body').on({
        'mousewheel': function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });

    if(comp==0){

        console.log("COMP =" +comp);
        comp++;

        new_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();

        console.log("YOU SCROLLED, NEW CURRENT POSITION IS :" +new_scroll_position);

        if (new_scroll_position > current_scroll_position){ //scroll going down



            console.log(new_scroll_position +" > "+ current_scroll_position +" GOING DOWN");




                $('body').animate({

                    scrollTop: second
                }, 500,
                function(){ //callback function for completed animation
                    completed_animation_scroll = true;
                    current_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();

                    console.log(" ANIMATING ");
                    console.log("CURRENT SCROLL POSITION = " +current_scroll_position);
                    console.log("NEW SCROLL POSITION = " +new_scroll_position);
                    console.log("ANIMATION COMPLETED = " +completed_animation_scroll);
                    console.log(" ******************* ************************ ******************");

                    $('body').unbind('mousewheel');
                    comp = 0;




                 });




        }
        else{

            console.log(new_scroll_position +" > "+ current_scroll_position +" GOING DOWN");

                $('body').animate({

                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 500,
                function(){ //callback function for completed animation
                    completed_animation_scroll = true;
                    current_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();

                    console.log(" ANIMATING ");
                    console.log("CURRENT SCROLL POSITION = " +current_scroll_position);
                    console.log("NEW SCROLL POSITION = " +new_scroll_position);
                    console.log("ANIMATION COMPLETED = " +completed_animation_scroll);
                    console.log(" ******************* ************************ ******************");

                    $('body').unbind('mousewheel');
                    comp = 0;




                 });

        }
    }
});
});
```

Try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/81t6w6zv/2/

Comment: That's just horrible, tracking down an error in that code won't be easy. There's event handlers inside event handlers and all the variables are global, start by cleaning it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in fact that when scrolling animation is done (including success callback), `$(window).scroll` handler is triggered and works again (because scrolling animation is actually scrolling and `comp` becomes equal to `0`).

The easiest way to fix it is to wrap `comp = 0` in scrolling animation callback function with `setTimeout` (I changed type of `comp` variable to bool):

```
setTimeout
(
    function()
    {
        comp = false;
    },
    100
);
```

There are also some "not good things" like binding `mousewheel` event handler but not unbinding it (if `comp` not equals to `0`), so please take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/81t6w6zv/5/) to fix such problems in your code.

And full code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var comp = false;
    var current_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
    var secondOffsetTop = $("#second").offset().top;  

    $(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if (comp)
        {
            return;
        }
        comp = true;

        $('body').on('mousewheel', function()
        {
            return false;
        });

        var scrollTo = 0;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > current_scroll_position)
        {
            scrollTo = secondOffsetTop;
        }

        $('body').animate
        (
            {
                scrollTop: scrollTo
            },
            500,
            function()
            {
                current_scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();
                $('body').off('mousewheel');
                setTimeout
                (
                    function()
                    {
                        comp = false;
                    },
                    100
                );
            }
        );
    });
});
```